# how to add text to the miniature list block

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am creating a module for prestashop 1.7, and I would like to add a text inside this block but I do not know how to do it:

[image: a busy cat]

I do not know if to use a hook, and which one!

edit : without modifying the tpl file of the theme
Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this hook:

```
{hook h='displayProductPriceBlock' product=$product type="before_price"}
```

```
public function HookDisplayProductPriceBlock($params)
{
    if ($params['type'] == "before_price") {
        return 'TEXT'; // or return TPL file
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

On your module, you just need to register "displayProductPriceBlock" hook during installation process and add above function to yourmodule.php file.

Comment: thank's Mahdi but i have my module! how add informations at this block (only in my module) without modifying the template.
I do not see how!

Comment: It's OK. 1-register displayProductPriceBlock hook on your module installation 2- add above function to your main PHP file of your module